# jQuery mobile / phonegap not capturing swipe on second html page

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

** Thought I would post an update.

Apparently JQM can't handle pages in the way I was trying. So the page structure I wanted was this:

"index.html"
     |
     |-- Sub page 1
     |-- Sub page 2
     |-- Sub page 3 etc

"page2.html"
     |
     |-- Sub page 1
     |-- Sub page 2
     |-- Sub page 3 etc

and to use swipeleft or right to navigate between pages! Individual pages are fine but as soon as I go from "index.html" to "page2.html" mobile.changepage can't handle that and so "bugs" creep in.

**

I am trying to develop a jquery mobile (phonegap) app that utilises the swipe features and I am missing something here and I am sure that it will be a facepalm moment but I just cant get my head around this.

As I understand it, the way jqm works (best when calling pages with ajax) I need to load all the code for my site into the index.html file! That I have done. I then need to call $(document).on('pageinit', '#swipehome', function() for example to execute code at document load, init etc. But I can't seem to understand why I can't pickup events on the second page. I have two pages (will be more but 2 for testing this process) index.html & swipe.html

index.html has all the links to the *.js & *.css.
It calls swipe.html from a function slidepage

Now the crux of the problem, why aren't the swipe events on swipe.html being picked up?

As I understood it, with ajax page loading if you put js in the index.html page it links across and you can utilise that in the second page?

I have created a simple jsf to show what I need!

http://jsfiddle.net/bFM7B/

Basically I want the functionality in swipe.html page that has been linked from index.html

Any help appreciated!

George

Here's all the code!

** UPDATE TO main.JS ** I am now capturing the swipe event in the second page with the updated code below, **BUT** the page isn't changing!!!
"main.js"

```
/* === UPDATED CODE === */
$(document).on('swipe', '#swipehome', function() {
    console.log('Changing to #swipepage1');
    $.mobile.changePage('#swipepage1','slide',false,true);
    console.log('End');
});


    //Initialise the slider on the swipe page
$(document).on('pageinit', '#swipehome', function() {   
    $("#home").swiperight(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1",{ transition: "slide" , reverse: true});
    });

    $("#home").swipeleft(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page2",{ transition: "slide"});
    });

    $("#page1,#page2").swipe(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#swipehome", { transition: "fade"});
    });
});

//Initialise the slider on the test page
$(document).on('pageinit', '#testg', function() {   
    $('#foobar').bxSlider({
        touchEnabled: true,
        pager: false,
        pagerSelector: false
    });
});

$(document).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});

function slidePage(page) {
    $.mobile.changePage(page,{'transition': "slide"});
    console.log(page);
}
```

"index.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>swipe test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <!-- STYLESHEETS //-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

    <!-- JavaScripts //-->
    <script src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/database.js"></script>
    <script src="js/audio.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="start">   
        <div data-role="content">
            <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
                <a href="#" onClick="slidePage('swipe.html');" class="next" data-role="button" data-theme="a" style="width: 150px; margin: 0 auto;">Swipe</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

"swipe.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>
   <div data-role="page" id="swipehome">
   <div data-role="content">
    <p>Swipe left or right to change pages</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="content">
    <p>You Swiped right<br/>Swipe any direction to go back</p>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="content">
    <p>You Swiped left<br/>Swipe any direction to go back</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tell me one thing, do your second page has its own js file or is it everything inside a index.html js file?

Comment: You don't need to put all in one js. Personally I include 10 js files in my html page.

Comment: Sorry to be clear, I have more than one *.js file, but the only relevant one is main.js. The second page swipe.html does not have its own js file but I am using $(document).on('pageinit', '#swipehome', function() { to initialise functions for that page

Comment: Wait, does your second page also has an id swipehome? I mean page inside a swipe.html and a page inside a index.html?

Comment: I'll post all the code :-) makes life easier!

Comment: Ok, if it will make your life easier you can even mail them to me. I only want to see your index.html, swipe,html and main.js

Comment: Cheers Gajotres, posted above and will mail...

Comment: Feel like I am descending into the seven circles of hell here. I finally get the swipe action captured and now it seems there is a bug in same page changes that will effectively render what I have done useless!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pull all your javascript in one single js file.

Your problem most probably comes from the fact that at the moment you register your swipe callbacks, only the elements that are in index.html are registered and not the one in swipe.html. You need to re-register your swipe callbacks after the elements in swipe.html are loaded.

Comment: Ok, after a bit of hacking and a lot of coffee, I found 50% of the solution. Using $(document).on('event' I can pick up the swipe event from the swipe.html

    $(document).on('swipe', '#swipehome', function() { 
        alert('hhh');
        slidePage('swipe.html#swipepage1');
    });

It's still not changing pages but I am getting closer :)